# During a Drush pm-uninstall, is there a way to see what sql queries were run?

Tags: drush, installation

Is there a way to find out what sql queries were run during a drush pm-uninstall module? The reason I want to find out is because I want to see if certain tables were removed during the uninstall. Sometimes modules like ubercart leave orphaned tables even though you uninstall them. I had to find the hard way after installing and testing a few other modules and see my database tables balloon up.

Comment: I would look at devels query log and them figure out of there's a way to enable it during drush calls. It's my understanding that anything created with a proper hook_schema will always be removed during uninstall. Otherwise you've got a core bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to adapt the devel query log as Letharion suggested, but that would involve some coding.  I have done similar things (for a different purpose) by using the [Mysql General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html).  This requires restarting mysqld with an additional parameter, but beyond that minor inconvenience, works pretty well and shows you absolutely everything that's going on with the database.

Comment: do you have a screenshot of how that would look? And if I turn it on in my production, would it affect performance?  thanks greg!

Comment: Don't turn it on in production! It logs a lot, so performance and space are significantly impacted. Don't leave it on for very long.  I haven't had this enabled for a long time, so I don't have screenshots, but it basically produces a log file full of SQL queries.